# Getting / adding eloquent models to cache

Tags: php, mysql, caching, eloquent, laravel-5

I've recently started to dig into Laravel 5 and I'm really "digging" it. (heh, heh, get it? ... Sorry.)

Anyways. In my code, I noticed that, with relationships, eloquent does a TON of queries to retrieve said relationships, or load them. I'm attempting to cache the results of these relationships, so that (hopefully), I can reduce the number of queries down to very little, and instead pull from the cache.

In earlier versions of Laravel, I know it was possible to run something like `User::with('stuff')->remember(5)->get()`, which would retrieve the results and cache them automatically. However, as seen under the [Eloquent Caching section in Laravel's upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0), that's no longer possible.

My question is, how should one go about achieving model caching now? I'd like to cache either the parent with all its relations, or (preferably), the individual models themselves, and then check cache for them before pulling. I looked into adding an event listener to all queries via `Event::listen('illuminate.query')` that would check the cache before querying the database, but I don't really know how to return the result from that listener.

I feel like I'm on the right path here but I'm missing something. Any advice or extra information would be super helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you're on right track... This event is dispatched after query execution. Create repository for eloquent calls, then decorate it adding cache feature.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I just ran a test where I enabled query logging, ran a DB call, then in the listener echoed out `DB::getQueryLog()`. The array was empty, so it was happening before the query itself happened.

Comment: @JamesSpence query logging is disabled by default. Make sure to enable it with `DB::enableQueryLog()`

Comment: @lukasgeiter I did, I didn't include that in my little code snippet. It currently looks like this (please excuse the one line treatment): `DB::enableQueryLog(); //Run query here` and then in my event listener `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: @JamesSpence Not getting into details of your test, the event is dispatched after the query has been executed https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L580-L594 - it is fired in the `logQuery` method. Anyway, hooking on the event to replace the result is not a good idea - that's what I meant by not being on the right track.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk ah, so it's executed before it's added to the log, but after we have the results? I wonder why that's the way it is...

Anyways. Do you have an idea as to how I can achieve this? I need to stop the query being processed if the item exists in the cache, otherwise continue on. I could override the with function and try and do it there, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that.

Comment: Like in my first comment - create a repository pulling data from the db, then decorate it with caching function (ie. craete another one implementing the same interface, but pulling data from cache if it exists, fallback to the db query if not - that is `decorator` pattern). It will be easy to test, maintain, extend

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the second part of that comment. I've heard mentionings of Repositories, so I'll look into them! Thanks.